# What's the C++ equivalent of %x.ys format specifier from C?

Tags: c++, string, io

How can I replace `printf()` with `cout`?
My Code In C++:

```
    #include<iostream>
    #include<cstdio>
    using namespace std;
    int main ()
    {
        char st[15]="United Kingdom";
        printf("%5s\n",st);
        printf("%15.6s\n",st);
        printf("%-15.6s\n",st);
        printf("%.3s\n",st); // prints "Uni"
        return 0;
    }
```

The Code Prints:

```
United Kingdom

       United

United

Uni
```

How can I manipulate like this in C++?

Comment: Post what output you are trying to generate.

Comment: I don't think that code you posted is C.

Comment: Try it out, you will know if it works or not!  Then ask for help if it doesn't.  http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Comment: Your code is C++ which uses C libraries. The idiomatic way in C++ is to use the `std::string` type instead of character arrays, `std::cout` instead of `printf` and stream manipulators for formatting. If you are looking for a direct analogy of `printf`'s format specifiers there isn't one.

Comment: Look into [Boost Format](https://theboostcpplibraries.com/boost.format).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `std::setw()` I/O manipulator is the direct equivalent of `printf()`'s *minimum width* for strings, and the `std::left` and `std::right` I/O manipulators are the direct equivalent for justification within the output width.  But there is no direct equivilent of `printf()`'s *precision* (max length) for strings, you have to truncate the string data manually.

Try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    char st[15] = "United Kingdom";

    cout << setw(15) << st << '\n'; // prints " United Kingdom"
    cout << setw(5) << st << '\n'; // prints "United Kingdom"
    cout << setw(15) << string(st, 6) << '\n'; // prints "         United"
    cout << left << setw(15) << string(st, 6) << '\n'; // prints "United         "
    cout << setw(15) << string(st, 0) << '\n'; // prints "               "
    cout << string(st, 3) << '\n'; // prints "Uni"
    cout << st << '\n; // prints "United Kingdom"

    return 0;
}
```

[Live demo](https://ideone.com/BSKtqb)

Answer (score 1):

The std::setw() iomanip will set the field width for insertions, that is, even if the isinsertions shorter than the specified lenth it will get padded to that amount, std::setfill() sets the padding character.

For example:

```
std::cout << std::setw(20) << std::setfil('0') << "hey you!" << std::endl;
```

would print "Hey you!000000000000\n" (possibly \r\n instead of just \n if you're using Windows). There is also std::left which would cause the padding to precede rather than follow the insert.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for [Boost.Format](https://www.boost.org/libs/format).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <boost/format.hpp>

int main()
{
    std::string st = "United Kingdom";
    std::cout << boost::format("%15s\n") % st;
    std::cout << boost::format("%5s\n") % st;
    std::cout << boost::format("%15.6s\n") % st;
    std::cout << boost::format("%-15.6s\n") % st;
    std::cout << boost::format("%15.0s\n") % st;
    std::cout << boost::format("%.3s\n") % st; // prints "Uni"
    std::cout << boost::format("%s\n") % st;
}
```

<kbd>[Live example](https://wandbox.org/permlink/iZzq1kVYddOn7cP7)</kbd>